# Bash Shell - Print names of all self-referential files

Tags: unix, for-loop

The idea is the write a bash script that prints the names of files in the current directory that contain their own name in their content.

e.g if a file called hello contains the string hello, we print hello, and we do this for all files in the current directory

Here's what I wrote, and I have no idea why it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *
do
  if (cat $file | grep $file) 2> /dev/null
  then
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

Fixed:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *
do
  if grep $file $file 2> /dev/null
  then
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

Comment: Please make sure to validate your script here: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Please also add to your question what "doesn't work" means, specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from quoting issues, potential regex escaping issues, and the useless use of `cat` and `(...)`, your code should work *in principle*.

Try this version - if it doesn't work, something else must be going on:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *
do
  if grep -qF "$file" "$file" 2> /dev/null
  then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

- `-q` makes `grep` not output matching lines (whether a match was found is implied by the exit code).
- `-F` ensures that the search term is treated as a *literal* (rather than a regex).